# call the function in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination

First I include the pagination

```
include("pagination.php");
define("PAGINATION_LIMIT_PER_PAGE",8);
//get current page number from url, and calculation
if(isset($_GET['page'])) $page=$_GET['page'];
//default page number is 1 and start from item 1
else $page=1;

//initialize pagination variable
$start = ($page-1) * PAGINATION_LIMIT_PER_PAGE;

$stmt  = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM auction_items');
$rows  = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total = count($rows);
```

After that I select the items store into variable

```
 $querySel     = "SELECT * FROM auction_items WHERE Item_Title LIKE :title AND Item_Expired >= NOW() AND Item_Status = 'available' ORDER BY Item_Expired ASC LIMIT ".$start.",".PAGINATION_LIMIT_PER_PAGE;

  $galleryDetails = "";
```

After that I use JSON encode to push the value to the AJAX success

```
$galleryDetails .=' '.pagination($page, $total).'';
print json_encode(['type'=>'3', 'passValue'=>$galleryDetails]);
```

**Question**:

how can I pass the `pagination($page, $total)` to the variable, above code cant work.
How can i call the pagination function?

Comment: $galleryDetails .=' '.pagination($page, $total);.''; You have a semicolon here. You need to remove it.

Comment: remove ald ...cant work

Comment: what error you are facing ?

Comment: i cant call `pagination($page, $total)` function

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to debug your code step-by-step.

1. First of all, try to `var_dump($galleryDetails);`, and see if it returns what you want.
2. If it does then check you AJAX function, but try to simplify your received data. Comment everything in you searchAuction.php file and JUST echo `json_encode(['type'=>'3']);` this code. In the AJAX function JUST `alert(data['type']);` in you success method and comment everything else inside of it. This way you will know if your AJAX call works correctly and receives valid data. If it does->
3. Uncomment your `$galleryDetails` code and adjust your JSON data. Uncomment your code in the AJAX function and try to run it to receive what you want.

Don't try to debug the whole code. It is too complicated. Make sure that every single block of your code works and then join these working blocks step by step.